# JNA - Map Native Windows Data Types (IN and OUT parameters)

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am trying to use the Windows API of an IP-USB-Hub (AnywhereUSB) in Java with JNA. I managed to load the dll and now I have to map the functions.
I have the header file which declares an enum and some functions like shown as follows:

```
typedef enum AWUSB_STATUS_tag{
    AWUSB_STATUS_CONNECTED,
    AWUSB_STATUS_ALREADY_CONNECTED,
    AWUSB_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER,
    AWUSB_STATUS_TIMEOUT,
    AWUSB_STATUS_CANCELLED,
    AWUSB_STATUS_SUCCESS,
    ...
}AWUSB_STATUS, *PAWUSB_STATUS;
```

and

```
AWUSB_STATUS AwUsbGetConnectionStatus (
   IN   LPCWSTR Hub,
   OUT  PDWORD  IpAddress,
   OUT  PAWUSB_STATUS   Status,
   IN   DWORD   Timeout,
   IN   HANDLE  hEvent OPTIONAL
);
```

What irritates me, are the IN, OUT and OPTIONAL parameters. 
I do not really understand what those tags mean.
How do I handle them in Java?

So far I declared them like this in Java:

```
    public static interface AWUSB_STATUS_tag {
        public static final int AWUSB_STATUS_CONNECTED = 0;
        public static final int AWUSB_STATUS_ALREADY_CONNECTED = 1;
        public static final int AWUSB_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER = 2;
        public static final int AWUSB_STATUS_TIMEOUT = 3;
        ...
    };

    int AwUsbGetConnectionStatus(WString Hub, int IpAdress, IntBuffer Status, int Timeout, Pointer hEvent);
```

Are the Mappings correct? And what do I need to do to be able to call the function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess they are just place holders. Usually IN means normal const var, OUT means the arg is a mutable pointer, OPTIONAL means a pointer that can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, "OUT" means that you need to pass a pointer value, usually a variable reference of the form `&my_variable`.  JNA provides `XXXByReference` types for this purpose for primitives, and you can define your own.  You create an instance of that type of parameter, and then use `getValue()` to retrieve the "result", e.g.

```
IntByReference iref = new IntByReference();
lib.myCall(iref);
int value = iref.getValue();
```

You can use `String` in place of `WString` if you set the default type mapper to do so (refer to the default initializations of other windows API library mappings).

```
MyLib mylib = (MyLib)Native.loadLibrary("mylib", W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```

For this native code:

```
AWUSB_STATUS AwUsbGetConnectionStatus (
   IN   LPCWSTR Hub,
   OUT  PDWORD  IpAddress,
   OUT  PAWUSB_STATUS   Status,
   IN   DWORD   Timeout,
   IN   HANDLE  hEvent OPTIONAL
);

// Java mapping
int AwUsbGetConnectionStatus(String Hub, DWORDByReference IpAddress, IntByReference Status, DWORD Timeout, HANDLE hEvent);
```

Those "OUT" parameters need to be of pointer type.